# How to do condition for pathname?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, pathname

Hi i need to do  if Statement for pathname.
That's how i trying to do this but it's doesn't work.

```
if (pathname == "/") {
    category = 'home';
    pagetype = 'homepage';
}
```

If pathname is like that the script should show `category : home` and `pagetype : homepage`.
Thanks for help

Comment: I can past the whole code if you need

Comment: No, post your [MCVE], as instructed in the Help Centre.

Comment: "It's doesn't work" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: What part of your code doesn't work

Comment: Can you add the error that you are getting?

Comment: Only this part doesn't work beacuse i'm trying to change only this thing.

Comment: It's saying that pathname is not defined

Comment: Are you trying to get the URL path?

Comment: at the top of the code i have var url = window.location.href; that is getting the url form site

Comment: where is `pathname` declared and assigned? you must show that for a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do i have to get path url ? i don't understand

Comment: in that case you want `if (window.location.pathname == "/")`

Comment: i didn't declare pathname any where in my code i thgouth if i get teh url adress i also get pathname

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL you need to use [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

For the URL "http://www.google.com/images":

```
window.location.href; // http://www.google.com/images
window.location.hostname; // www.google.com
window.location.pathname; // /images
window.location.protocol; // http://
```

So, you will probably need:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
    category = 'home';
    pagetype = 'homepage';
}
```

or if you are using ES6 you can also use:

```
const { pathname } = window.location;

if (pathname === '/') {
    category = 'home';
    pagetype = 'homepage';
}
```

Comment: Thanks i didn't know there is a window.location.pathname,

Comment: Try running `console.log(window.location)` and you will be able to see all of the properties